# Comparable interface sorting method not working

Tags: java, interface

I tried to implement the comparable interface on an array list of BankAccounts however, I got major errors,when trying to compile and run the main method of the tester class specifically about the Collection.sort(list) line. It's saying that it doesn't recognize the syntax..looked online and through javadoc and I can't find where I am wrong..

```
public class BankAccount implements Comparable { //QUESTION 2.1
  /**
  A bank account has a balance that can be changed by 
  deposits and withdrawals.
 */
  private int accountNumber;
   private double balance; 
  /**
  Constructs a bank account with a zero balance
  @param anAccountNumber the account number for this account
  */
  public BankAccount(int anAccountNumber)
  {   
  accountNumber = anAccountNumber;
  balance = 0;
  }

   /**
  Constructs a bank account with a given balance
  @param anAccountNumber the account number for this account
  @param initialBalance the initial balance
```

*/
      public BankAccount(int anAccountNumber, double initialBalance)
      {
        accountNumber = anAccountNumber;
        balance = initialBalance;
      }

```
  /**
  Gets the account number of this bank account.
  @return the account number
  */
  public int getAccountNumber()
  {   
   return accountNumber;
   } 

  /**
  Deposits money into the bank account.
  @param amount the amount to deposit
  */
  public void deposit(double amount)
  {  
   double newBalance = balance + amount;
   balance = newBalance;
  }

  /**
  Withdraws money from the bank account.
  @param amount the amount to withdraw
  */
   public void withdraw(double amount)
   {   
     double newBalance = balance - amount;
     balance = newBalance;
   }

  /**
   Gets the current balance of the bank account.
   @return the current balance
  */
   public double getBalance()
   {   
     return balance;
   }


   public int compareTo (BankAccount temp) {


     if (balance<temp.balance) 
         return -1;
     if (balance==temp.balance) 
         return 0;
     return 1;
  }

}

 public class TestSortedBankAccounts {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Put bank accounts into a list 
        ArrayList<BankAccount> list = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();

        BankAccount ba1 = new BankAccount(100, 500); //Constructor acctNumber and balance
        BankAccount ba2 = new BankAccount(200, 10000);
        BankAccount ba3 = new BankAccount(300, 400);
        BankAccount ba4 = new BankAccount(600, 0);
        BankAccount ba5 = new BankAccount(800, 50);

        list.add(ba1);
        list.add(ba2);
        list.add(ba3);
        list.add(ba4);
        list.add(ba5);

        // Call the library sort method
        Collections.sort(list);

        // Print out the sorted list 
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            BankAccount b = list.get(i);
            System.out.println(b.getBalance());
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE: TestSortedBankAccounts.java:26: error: no suitable method found for sort(ArrayList)
      Collections.sort(list);
                 ^
    method Collections.sort(List,Comparator) is not applicable
      (cannot instantiate from arguments because actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Collections.sort(List) is not applicable
      (inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
        inferred: BankAccount
        bound(s): Comparable)
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in method sort(List,Comparator)
    T#2 extends Comparable declared in method sort(List)
1 error

Comment: It helps if you post the error messages. **WARNING** Do not do == for floating-point values, due to FP rounding errors.

Comment: You could use something like `balance - temp.balance` instead - let's also not discuess the fact that your example won't compile ;)

Comment: Error message is above @Darien

Comment: @Darien Can you please post a reference for your warning? What rounding errors can occur if both operands are doubles?

Comment: @Muel Here, try it yourself: `((1.00d - 0.90d) - 0.10d)` should come out as `-2.7755575615628914E-17`. I have a [partial explanation here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/536275), but it's just a problem you *always* have to be aware of with FP math, the same way that integer math can always truncate the decimal portion. Avoid `==` and instead look for "close enough for my purposes". (The maximum percentage it can be "off", [machine epsilon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon), is a much more complicated topic.)

Comment: @Darien If you are doing FP arithmetic, I totally agree. However, `==` without arithmetic is perfectly safe: `double x, y; if (x == y) {}`. Your first comment is presently open to misinterpretation! :P

Comment: @Muel Equality is arithmetical :p (Alternately, if you aren't doing arithmetic with it, then what's the point of the datatype?)

Answer (score 4):

You are implementing the raw version of `Comparable`.  You should implement the generic form of `Comparable`:

```
public class BankAccount implements Comparable<BankAccount> {
```

If you implement the raw form, then the parameter type on `compareTo` would be `Object`.  With the generic form, you can supply the generic type parameter as a parameter to `compareTo` as you already have.

Comment: I executed your code myself (supplying the necessary 2-arg `BankAccount` constructor myself) and it works.  Based on the error message that you just now supplied, there must be other code you're not supplying.

Comment: Thanks for supplying your entire code.  However, I can still get your code to run correctly if I add `<BankAccount>` as in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

My answer (that I've tried and it works):

```
public class BankAccount implements Comparable<Object> { // <-- 
  /**
  A bank account has a balance that can be changed by 
  deposits and withdrawals.
 */
  private int accountNumber;
   private double balance; 
  /**
  Constructs a bank account with a zero balance
  @param anAccountNumber the account number for this account
  */
  public BankAccount(int anAccountNumber)
  {   
  accountNumber = anAccountNumber;
  balance = 0;
  }

   /**
  Constructs a bank account with a given balance
  @param anAccountNumber the account number for this account
  @param initialBalance the initial balance
  */ 
  public BankAccount(int anAccountNumber, double initialBalance) {
      accountNumber = anAccountNumber; balance = initialBalance; }

  /**
  Gets the account number of this bank account.
  @return the account number
  */
  public int getAccountNumber()
  {   
   return accountNumber;
   } 

  /**
  Deposits money into the bank account.
  @param amount the amount to deposit
  */
  public void deposit(double amount)
  {  
   double newBalance = balance + amount;
   balance = newBalance;
  }

  /**
  Withdraws money from the bank account.
  @param amount the amount to withdraw
  */
   public void withdraw(double amount)
   {   
     double newBalance = balance - amount;
     balance = newBalance;
   }

  /**
   Gets the current balance of the bank account.
   @return the current balance
  */
   public double getBalance()
   {   
     return balance;
   }


   // public int compareTo (BankAccount temp) { // <-- WRONG
   public int compareTo(Object temp){ // <-- RIGHT

     BankAccount other = (BankAccount)temp; // <-- Cast to BankAccount
     if (balance<other.balance) 
         return -1;
     if (balance==other.balance) 
         return 0;
     return 1;
  }

}
```